# Angular 2.0.0 - Final Release - Mocking/Overriding Components

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I have create mock versions of my components. How do I integrate then in the unit testing so that **TestBed.configureTestingModule** will pick them up instead of the unmocked versions of the components?

I have a **componentA.component.ts** that contains **componentB.component.ts**. **componentB.component.ts** also contains **componentC.component.ts**. How do I mock/override this? Please help.

Comment: Add the mock the declarations and don't add the real one. Only thing that is available is what you declare.

Comment: If you're testing A and A contains B and B contains C. There's no need to event involve C (mock or otherwise). The mock  for B can do anything you want it to do, as long as it allows you to test behavior for A. Making deep component mocks is not a good idea. Just keep it one level

Comment: C has a value/variable that is needed by A to perform its function.

Comment: Like I said you can make B do anything you want. It is just a mock. You can make it so that it has the responsibilities of C. It doesn't matter. I a mock shouldn't need any external dependencies. The point of the mock is the test the component that's using it. The component being tested doesn't need to know anything about the internals of the mock, as long as it allows it to be tested

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thanks.